# Construct System of linear equations with 2 behaviors

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

If $5\%$ of people that see your ad, click on it and go to your website,
$6\%$ of those that click buy $1$ product,
and $3\%$ of those who click buy $2$ products.

how many people need to see the ad, in order to sell $7500$ products?

I don't know how what kind of equations I should build.

First one is:

$C = P\times0.05 (5\%$ of people P turn to Clickers C)

But Second one, I'm not sure:

$X_1 =C\times0.06 (6 \%$ of Clickers C, turns into X unit sold)

$X_2 =C\times0.03 (3 \%$ of Clickers C, turns into 2X unit sold)

and $X_2 = 2\times X_1$ (Two times X units sold are one time 2X units are sold)

and we require that 7500 units will be sold, and they are composed from $X_2$ and $X_1$ so:

$7500 = X_1+X_2$

And to take everything:

$7500=3\times X_1$

$X_1 = 2500$

$2500 = 0.06\times C$
$C= 41,666,666$
$P = 833,333.33$

But it doesn't make sense. Answer should be $1,250,000$

Answer (score 1):

Let total number of people be  $x$ .

People who see your ad : $\dfrac{5x}{100}$

People who buy one product : $\dfrac{5x}{100} \times \dfrac6{100} = \dfrac{3x}{1000}$

People who buy two products : $\dfrac{3x}{2000}$.

According to the question :

$$\dfrac{3x}{1000} + 2\times\dfrac{3x}{2000} = 7500$$

Can you complete the rest ?

Comment: I don't understand the constrction process
1.Why for "people who buy.." you just write it in writing, and not give it some value?
2. How did your reach the final equation?

Comment: Because we are still unsure of the variable $x$ . Therefore , we cannot assign the value  and use algebra to find the value of $x$.

Comment: sorry, I don't mean a value, I meant a variable. Anyway, still not sure how you reached the final equation. why do you double them with 2 ?

Comment: Since you are buying **Two** products.

Comment: I understand the logic, but I'd like to see this also as an equation. What  I want is to see the whole equation system, without any number, other than the percentages, and only than input the values.  Imagine I'll need to use such equations for computation script - I need a more methodological way to show it.

Comment: Have you tried to solve the last equation and find the value of $x$ ?

Comment: Yes, solving the final equation was not a problem. Just thinking about how to set up the equations is the problem.